# SOQL: How to create a subquery based on a non-primary field?

Tags: soql

I'm sure this would have been asked before, but I'm unable to find a similar question.

We're doing some analysis in our Prod org using Inspector/Dev Console and would like to run what on the face of it is a simple query to return Contacts that have emails listed in the Leads table.

In SQL, this would be:

`SELECT Email from Contact where Email in (Select Email from Lead)`

I'm struggling to work out how to perform this using SOQL.  Because this is a Prod org, I cannot create any helper fields or Apex classes without taking these through the change management and business approval process.

Answer (score 2):

SOQL has no support for joins on a non-primary field. The best you can do is query the records from one table to generate a filter, then run that filter on a second query.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll need to work out how to do this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way around using 2 separate queries here. Subqueries in SOQL must work on a relationship or Id field.

You can use anonymous apex (Debug -> Execute Anonymous Window in the Developer Console, VSCode and SFDX also allow easy execution of anonymous code) to do this, though you'd have to put in some work to get data out in a usable format. You would have to keep the 50k row limit in mind though.

Another option you could explore would be to use the Salesforce-provided Data Loader to export your Leads and Contacts from production, and then use Excel (with a vlookup or similar function) to match on email.

Comment: Yeah, my colleague has already gone ahead with the export into Excel route to do some quick-and-dirty vlookups